# Host Server minecraft or samp

Tags: server, games

Is it possible to run a Minecraft- or SA-MP-Server (GTA San Andreas Multiplayer) on Ubuntu. If yes, how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

To get a Minecraft server running is very easy: Just download the Server JAR from [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/download) (Multiplayer Server -> second paragraph)
However I recommend using [Bukkit](http://dl.bukkit.org/), a 3rd party Minecraft server with plugin support.

SA-MP servers only exist for Windows, so you could decide to run one using Wine/PlayOnLinux, but this wouldn't be effective and the server might be slow and instable. Unless you want to do this, there's no possibility to run a SA-MP server on any Linux system.